# se me sale el background color de la caja que he creado

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

No se porque dentro de el div que tengo la caja sombra todo cuadra perfectamente hasta que le meto un el `background:color` con cualquier color y se sale. Saben porque?

```css
.cajaSombra {
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 1px rgba(3, 1, 32, 0.3);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

.BotonAzul {
  border-radius: 1em;
  border: none;
  background-color: var(--third-color);
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 1em 0em;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!--suscripciones-->
            <div class="col-6">
                <h2 class="h2 m-0 titulos">Suscripciones</h2>
                <hr>
                <!--Plan suscripcion -->
                <p>Plan actual:No tiene ningun plan seleccionado</p>

                <p>Elige el plan que mejor se adapte al número de ususarios y a las prestaciones que necesites</p>
                <!--boton ver planes -->
                <button class="BotonAzul">Ver Planes</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="cajaSombra">
                    <h2 class="h2 titulos">Facturas Emitidas</h2>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row">
                        <!--Numero de factura -->           
                        <div class="col-4  bg-black">
                            <h3 class="h3">Numero factura</h3>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Fecha -->
                        <div class="col-4 text-center">
                            <h3 class="h3 m-0">Fecha</h3>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Descarga PDF -->
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <h3 class="h3 m-0">Descargar PDF</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te pasa porque te sobre sale tendras puesto algun tipo de margen o algo similar. En el codigo que has pasado no se be donde esta el fondo oscuro, pero como veras en el css la priemra clase de todas te he agreado un **overflow:hidden** eso lo que realiza es que todo lo que sobre salga de la caja que no se vea.

```css
.cajaSombra {
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 1px rgba(3, 1, 32, 0.3);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.BotonAzul {
  border-radius: 1em;
  border: none;
  background-color: var(--third-color);
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 1em 0em;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!--suscripciones-->
            <div class="col-6">
                <h2 class="h2 m-0 titulos">Suscripciones</h2>
                <hr>
                <!--Plan suscripcion -->
                <p>Plan actual:No tiene ningun plan seleccionado</p>

                <p>Elige el plan que mejor se adapte al número de ususarios y a las prestaciones que necesites</p>
                <!--boton ver planes -->
                <button class="BotonAzul">Ver Planes</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="cajaSombra">
                    <h2 class="h2 titulos">Facturas Emitidas</h2>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row">
                        <!--Numero de factura -->           
                        <div class="col-4  bg-black">
                            <h3 class="h3">Numero factura</h3>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Fecha -->
                        <div class="col-4 text-center">
                            <h3 class="h3 m-0">Fecha</h3>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Descarga PDF -->
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <h3 class="h3 m-0">Descargar PDF</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </main>
```

Comment: que solucion mas corta muchas gracias^^